# Can't get to work multiple async chain functions on angular 2

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I'm currently learning Angular 2 I'm sorry If i'm too noob, but I seem unable to get work multiple chain async functions...

I will try to explain and abbreviate my code, I'm requesting a get method to the API, it's a list of employees, the list of employees must be displayed in a table that's currently working perfect the table is called "listToDisplay", but the problem is when the calendar display, that it doesn't show me any birthdate that I'm filling up in the listEmployeeBirthday

I have figured out that when I call the updateCalendar method the system doesn't wait the listEmployeeBirthday to be filled out, as I showed in the code I console log the listEmployeeBirthday and it fills correctly but a warn message appears: "Value below was evaluated just now". I have tried everything to get this fix, but I don't seem to get work that updateCalendar execute just after getEmployees finish.

I would appreciate any help

```
ngOnInit(){

  this.getEmployees()

  this.updateCalendar()

  console.log("listEmployeeBirthday")

}



getEmployees(){

  this.http.get("apiadress...")
      .flatMap((response:Response) => response.json());
      .map((employee)=>{
        this.addCalendar(employee);
        this.listToDisplay.push(employee)
        })
      .subscribe();
}

addCalendar(employee){
  this.listEmployeeBirthday.push(employee.birthdate);
}


updateCalendar(){
  methodToUpdateCalendar(this.listEmployeeBirthday)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your `updateCalendar` function doesn't do anything because `getEmployees` is asynchronous. So you need to update calendar when employee is loaded:

```
this.http.get("apiadress...")
  .flatMap((response:Response) => response.json())
  .map((employee)=>{
    this.addCalendar(employee);
    this.listToDisplay.push(employee);
  })
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.updateCalendar();
  });
```

Btw the `map` operator should be used to actually map data, not for doing some actions. Better way is:

```
this.http.get("apiadress...")
  .flatMap((response:Response) => response.json())
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.addCalendar(employee);
    this.listToDisplay.push(employee);

    this.updateCalendar();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should resolve the listEmployeeBirthday() which is loaded before. In angular we can resolve the service before route is activated. Please go through the link below.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html

create a resolve like below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { yourservice } from './yourservice';

@Injectable()
export class AppResolve implements Resolve<any> {
constructor(private dropDownService: DropDownService) { }
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any[] {
    return listEmployeeBirthday;// return your service here.
}
}
```

Add above resolve in appModule providers.
and in router add like below.

```
 { path: 'currentRoute',  component: component, resolve: [resolveMethodcreatedabove]},
```

And in your current component get the resolved service like below

```
 import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
 constructor(private currentRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 

 }
 ngOnInit() {
     this.currentRoute.data.subscribe(data => listEmployeeBirthday = data);
  }
```